# Only the simulator from Xcode is showing the correct launch screen color

Tags: swift, xcode, background-color, info.plist, launch-screen

I added the Launch Screen row in the Info.plist. Then I added a Background color and an Image Name row under the Launch Screen. Both the color and the image is in the Assets correctly. But, when I run it on my iPhone, it only shows the image, not the color. When I run it on the simulator, it properly shows both the image and the color. I want the color to be displayed on the actual device as well.

Comment: Try deleting the app from your device, reboot it, and try again.

Comment: @meaning-matters I have already tried that. Still the same result

Answer (score 1):

Try solution suggested here : http://arsenkin.com/launch_screen_image_cache.html

Which says,
Name your new image differently from the one there was before in case your new one has the same name as the old one and put it out of the *.xcassets folder to the project directory and reference it in your UIImageView. And that's it.